# sbt equivalent of gradle's JavaExec

Tags: scala, gradle, sbt

Is there an equivalent of gradle's `JavaExec` task in sbt? Here's an example from the docs to understand what I'm looking for:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

  main = 'package.Main'

  // arguments to pass to the application
  args 'appArg1'
}
```

I need to configure classpath, main and pass some args - as in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`runner`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/3269eae533a534a00d1fd41cebffbcd3b4fba099/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L264) seems to be similar to gradle's `JavaExec`, for example

```
val runApp = taskKey[Unit]("sbt equivalent of gradle's JavaExec")
runApp := {
  (runner in Compile).value.run(
    mainClass = "example.Main",
    classpath = (fullClasspath in Runtime).value.files,
    options = Array("appArg1"),
    log = streams.value.log
  )
}
```